# How can i make a input field inside a card by clicking on the created card?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascrip html and css. 
Well I wanted to practice a bit. So I created a button. When I clicked on it a new small card appeared on the screen. That works totally fine. Well now I am trying to do a function that when I click on a created card it opens two input fields with a save button and a cancel button. I know how to programm the save and cancel button but I don't know how I can make them in a created card by clicking on the created card. Does somebody of you know how I can do this with Js? I really got no idea how I can do it with js.
This is my Code:

```
<button class="plus">
    <div class="item">
        <p>+</p>
    </div>
    <form name="theform">
        <input class="input-feld" type="text"><br>
        <input class="input-feld "type="text"><br>
        <input type="button" onClick="new Person()" value="Speichern">
        <input type="button" onClick="new Person()" value="Abbrechen">
    </form>
</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button.plus").on("click", function () {
        $("div:last").after("<div class=item><p>Title</p></div>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code looks messed up because you have the form html inside the button tag, Separate the button html, your card html.

Below is a working example.

Idea is

- Have a separate button which will add cards when clicked
- Have a card prototype which you can `clone` and add to body to create new cards
- Have a hidden form inside each card which is shown only when you click on the card
- use `Event Delegation` to trigger click events on dynamically added cards.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button.plus").on("click", function () {
        var newCard = $('#cardPrototype').clone(true); // clone the card html
        $(newCard).css('display','block').removeAttr('id');
        $('#newCardHolder').append(newCard);
    });
    
    $('body').on('click','.card',function(){ // event delegation syntax
      $(this).find('form').show();    
    });
});
```

```css
.card{
  background-color:yellow;
  padding:5px;
  width:200px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="plus">
  <div class="item">
    <p>+</p>
  </div>
</button>

<div id="newCardHolder">


</div>

<div id="cardPrototype" class="card" style="display:none;">
  <span> This is a Random Card</span>
  <form name="theform" style="display:none;">
    <input class="input-feld" type="text">
    <br>
    <input class="input-feld " type="text">
    <br>
    <input type="button" onClick="new Person()" value="Speichern">
    <input type="button" onClick="new Person()" value="Abbrechen">
  </form>
</div>
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful

Comment: @Reto.K glad I could help

Comment: One more question: Is it possible to make the text "this is a random card" disapear as soon as you click the card.  $(this).find("span").disapear(); sadly this dident work

Comment: `$(this).find('span').remove()` removes the element from DOM OR use `$(this).find('span').hide()` will hide the element